ListBoxItem detail Font Size
(RAD STUDIO 12.1)
Is it a way to define the font size and style for the detail text in a ListBoxItem?
I tried doing this:
ListBoxItem.StylesData['detail.TextSettings.Font.Size'] := 14;
...but the text size didn't change.
Thank you very much!
